# Magento 1.9 Custom Math Pricing / Simple Product Issue with Price

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've installed an extension, Custom Math Pricing by Mico Solutions, and I am experiencing 2 issues with my site now.

Issue 1: When I customize the product, the price is updated correctly on the product page, however, when the product is sent to the cart, a portion of the price is missing (length x price per foot).  I checked in the database to look for the price and could only find records of the wrong price so the price is only showing for the product page.  The portion of the calculation that is missing from the price includes an attribute which is set as a variable rather than custom options.  The custom options calculate perfectly.

Issue 2: When I customize a simple product and add it to the cart, I cannot go back to that product page and customize it a second time, the price remains fixed on the "base" price.  Let's say the product has a base price of $10.00.  When I customize it, the price stays at $10.00 but is different in the cart.  I have to delete my browser cache and cookies in order to customize it again and by doing that, my cart is emptied.

So my question is, where in the code can I find the pricing that is being sent to the sales_flat_quote table in the database.  Additionally, how can I debug or correct the issue of customizing a product a 2nd time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've got an issue with conflicting extensions.  Your best bet is to go to the Admin modules section (Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced) and disable anything else that appears to deal with product pricing.  Reset the cache and index and try again.  I am somewhat familiar with this extension and it's not compatible with `configurable products`... make sure your products are `simple product` types when adding products.

Comment: I found out the hard way that the extension is only for simple products.  After disabling the extension, I made my own module which does almost the same thing but is fully custom to my needs.  Too bad I already spent the money to purchase it...  Thanks for the help!